# I can't read a member variable from within another member function

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I have a trouble about scope, I knew the solution but this isn't the problem.
I want to know why the member variable `xhrObj` unreadable from within an another member function, although that variable is global variable for that member function ?

[image]

Comment: It's because the value of `this` is dependent on the nature of the call to the containing function.

Comment: `onreadystatechange` is already a member function of `xhrObj`. This means that by doing `this.xhrObj.readystate` you're trying to access `xhrObj` ON `xhrObj`. you could try to replace `this.xhrObj.readyState` with`this.readyState`, and `this.xhrObj.responseText` to `this.responseText` inside `this.xhrObj.onreadystatechange`.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp: You are right, I forgot that way. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because xhrObj function `onreadystatechage` is asynchrous in nature and when it return after complete call `this` context is different inside the `onreadystatechage()` and hence `this.xhrObj` is not different.